# MySQL sharding in Golang

Tags: mysql, go, scaling, sharding, high-availability

I want to scale out my MySQL database into few servers using horizontal sharding. Let's imagine that I have 5 database servers (not replicas) and I want to distribute the data from users table between 5 database servers:

```
Shard 1 (192.168.1.1)
Shard 2 (192.168.1.2)
Shard 3 (192.168.1.3)
Shard 4 (192.168.1.4)
Shard 5 (192.168.1.5)
```

Now I want to connect to one of them depending on user_id (server_id = user_id % 5). I will do this on each API request from users in my Go application.

I'm using [go-sql-driver](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql) and standard database/sql package.

```
import "database/sql"
import _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

shard1, _ := sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@tcp(192.168.1.1:3306)/dbname")
shard2, _ := sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@tcp(192.168.1.2:3306)/dbname")
shard3, _ := sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@tcp(192.168.1.3:3306)/dbname")
...
```

There is a basic connection pool in the database/sql package, but there is not a lot of control on it. There are also few methods: SetMaxIdleConns, SetMaxOpenConns, SetConnMaxLifetime, but it looks that they work only with single database server at once.

The question is how to properly handle and pool database connections in my Golang application? How to work with multiple database servers in Golang?

Should I create a singleton object with connection map with *DB values, store all connections there and use them across the whole application? For example:

```
connections := make(map[string]interface{})
connections["shard1"] = shard1
connections["shard2"] = shard2
...
```

How to close connections or don't close them after SQL query execution?

Comment: There is no one-size-fits-all answer to this. There are a few libraries I've seen over the years that aim to help with this, but every time I've dealt with this, I've found it easier to write my own abstraction layer, for the simple reason that no two implementations ever have the same exact goals. Finding one that does exactly what you want is probably unlikely.

Comment: Take a look at Vitess, it's doing that and way more: https://vitess.io/

Comment: I hope that code does not open connections to all 5 shards, then use only 1.

Comment: @RickJames The question was exactly how to handle/open/close connection for all shards and use them. As no one has any ideas about this it looks like I will create a map with connections and open them at start of application. Then I will choose a proper connection from map for each API request and execute SQL queries.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer I heard about Vitess and thought to use it, but it looks like a black box and there is no a lot of documentation/tutorials/examples/community. Also I'm not sure that I will find a right solution if something goes wrong (for example, with resharding or something else). Do you use it in production?

Comment: @devops787 not personally. I work for Google and I know it's used in production and developed here.

Comment: @devops787 - Is your app is like a web server, it comes and goes, so you don't want to waste time making 5 connections, then use only 1.  If the app runs the whole time, then, sure, make 5 connections.

Comment: @RickJames It is a Go application, which compiles into executable binary. It runs the whole time, listen and serve HTTP requests. It is not a PHP application, which runs by webserver on each HTTP request.

Comment: @devops787 - Is the app single-threaded?  If so, sure, create 5 connections and use the appropriate one.  If it is multi-threaded, it gets more complex; first a question:  Will 5 threads suffice?

Comment: @devops787 I maintain Vitess. You can join the vitess Slack channel by following the top right link on vitess.io and get help that way. Also, PlanetScale now provides training, professional services and hosted solutions for Vitess.

Comment: @SuguSougoumarane ok. Thanks

Comment: @RickJames I'm not sure about this. As I know Golang utilizes one thread by default, but this not matter, because there are go-routines. They are a light version of threads and they can be runned in parallel mode.

Comment: @devops787 - I is probably folly to share a MySQL connection between "go-routines".

Comment: @RickJames That's why I ask how to do in right way in Golang.